# Fastest way to transfer data to new QNAP disk?

Tags: busybox, qnap

I have (just) added a new disk to my QNAP NAS. What is the fastest way to transfer all data from QNAP disk 2 (2TB, 80% used) to the new QNAP disk (disk 5, 4TB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is always on the 3th partition of a disk.
So disk 2 will be /dev/sdb3
If the disk is single mounted then SSH into the NAS and perform

Use `df` to see where /dev/sdb3 is mounted on. And what the device name of your new disk.

If this is i.e. `/share/MD0_DATA` then perform `# cp -rf /share/MD0_DATA/* /dev/sde3/`. Replace `/sde3/` with the name of your device. This should copy all data from the share of disk 2 to the disk 5 and will create also a share with all dir's and sub dir's. It will still take a lot off time because it's about 1.75 TB.